# Find string and move it up to the top of the document

Tags: vb.net

I've searched everywhere for this answer and I'm sorry if it's basic. I'm still very new to VB.Net. I appreciate everyone's help.

My problem is my script has a large file that have <Entity...> strings in it which are followed by content <body...> (as example) strings. The <Entity> strings are located all over the file. What I need to do is gather up all the <Entity> strings and move them up to the top document prologue. So they would be going between [ ]. So essentially the code would need to find the regex ^<ENTITY.*$ cut it and go to "[" and paste the content.

Any help you can give me would be great.

I've tried creating an array to do this and failed. Then thought of using a REGEX to grab the <Entity string but that failed.

I then tried file.Append and that didn't work.

This is the code I've come up with, but it's not working. In fact it takes a long time to build.

```
Dim regex = New Regex("<Entity.*$")
Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
Dim arrEntity(0 To -1) As String

Dim regexMatches = regex.Matches(fileName)
Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each match As Match In regexMatches
    'If <!ENTITY.*> is found write it to an array
    Dim entityLine = match.ToString
    finalValue.Append(arrEntity(i))
    i += 1
Next
'Go to top of document and write the entity list between []
```

The expected results would be the fileName document to have all the <Entity...> lines to be moved up in between the [ ] at the top of the document. There should be no other <Entity strings in the document except in the top prologue.

Example SGM file

```
<!DOCTYPE DOC PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//DTD 38784STD-BV7//EN"[
<!ENTITY cdcs_5-35.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_5-35.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-2a.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-2A.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<doc service="xs" docid="BKw46" docstat="formal" verstatpg="ver" cycle="1" chglevel="1">
<front numcols="1">
<idinfo>
<?Pub Lcl _divid="100" _parentid="0">
<tmidno>Life with Pets</tmidno>
<chgnum>Change 1</chgnum>
<chgdate>2 August 2018</chgdate>
<chghistory>
<chginfo>
<chgtxt>Change 1</chgtxt>
<date>2 August 2018</date>
</front>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-19.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-19.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_3-5.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_3-5.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<body numcols="1">
<chapter>
<title>This is chapter 1</title>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-5.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-5.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-24.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-24.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<para0>
<title>Climb the ladder immedietly</title>
<para>Retrieve the cat.</para></para0></chapter>
<chapter>
<title>Don't forget to feed the dog</title>
<para0>
<!ENTITY cdcs_4-48.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_4-48.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<title>Prep for puppies</title>
<para>Puppies are cute</para></para0>
</chapter>
</body>
</doc>
```

Comment: Is this actually an XML document? It would be really helpful to have a proper sample of the document structure.

Comment: It's an SGML document. I'll post an example.

Comment: Please post a short example of your original text structure, or upload a simple file somewhere and post the link.

Comment: @MuhammadAlnahrawy I posted an example

Comment: Shouldn't you use an SGML parser then?

Comment: @LarsTech not for what I'm doing. The files are parsed individually then brought back together for processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I tested this code with the sample text you have posted:

```
    Dim largeFilePath As String = "largeFilePath"
    Dim lines = File.ReadLines(largeFilePath).ToList 'don't use ReadAllLines
    Dim reg = New Regex("\<\!NOTATION.*$|\<\!ENTITY.*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim entities = From line In lines
                   Where reg.IsMatch(line)

    Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Dim idx = -1
    For Each s In entities
        idx = lines.IndexOf(s, idx + 1)
        dictionary.Add(idx, s)
    Next

    Dim deletedItems = 0
    For Each itm In dictionary
        lines.RemoveAt(itm.Key - deletedItems)
        deletedItems += 1
    Next

    For Each s In dictionary.Values
        lines.Insert(1, s)
    Next

    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("newfile.txt")
        For Each line As String In lines
            sw.WriteLine(line)
        Next
        sw.Flush()
        sw.Close()
    End Using
```

And here is the final result:

```
<!DOCTYPE DOC PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//DTD 38784STD-BV7//EN"[
<!ENTITY cdcs_4-48.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_4-48.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-24.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-24.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-5.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-5.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_3-5.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_3-5.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-19.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-19.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-2a.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-2A.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_5-35.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_5-35.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<doc service="xs" docid="BKw46" docstat="formal" verstatpg="ver" cycle="1" chglevel="1">
<front numcols="1">
<idinfo>
<?Pub Lcl _divid="100" _parentid="0">
<tmidno>Life with Pets</tmidno>
<chgnum>Change 1</chgnum>
<chgdate>2 August 2018</chgdate>
<chghistory>
<chginfo>
<chgtxt>Change 1</chgtxt>
<date>2 August 2018</date>
</front>
<body numcols="1">
<chapter>
<title>This is chapter 1</title>
<para0>
<title>Climb the ladder immedietly</title>
<para>Retrieve the cat.</para></para0></chapter>
<chapter>
<title>Don't forget to feed the dog</title>
<para0>
<title>Prep for puppies</title>
<para>Puppies are cute</para></para0>
</chapter>
</body>
</doc>
```

The code has been updated and tested on a **100 MB** file and the processing took only **2 seconds**!

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll look up the code so I understand it better.

Comment: I'm getting an error "Cannot read from a closed text reader on the Next in for each line in lines

Comment: I changed it and don't get the error anymore, now it does nothing and just hangs there

Comment: The code has been updated and tested on a 100 MB file and the processing took only 2 seconds!

Comment: I need to check for <!Notation too. Dim reg = New Regex("<!Entity.*$|<!Notation.*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) And just Regex("<!.*$) But got an error System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: It's also not removing the entities inside the document. So I have entities up top (awesome) but also entities within the document

Comment: Thank you @Muhammad Alnahrawy. This solved my problem

Comment: Glad to help. @MaxineHammett