# Function does not remove string from body of text

Tags: vb.net

Hi there this is a continuation of my question  [Find string and move it up to the top of the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55597861/find-string-and-move-it-up-to-the-top-of-the-document/55599820)

The code does almost what I need to to. It does search for <!Entity> elements and moves them to the top of the document, but it doesn't remove them from the body of the document. I also need to broaden the search to just <!.*$

Here is the code. On line 15 "lines.RemoveAt(item.Key)" it doesn't seem to be working

```
Dim largeFilePath As String = "largeFilePath"
Dim lines = File.ReadLines(largeFilePath).ToList 'don't use ReadAllLines
Dim reg = New Regex("<!Entity.*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim entities = From line In lines
               Where reg.IsMatch(line)

Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
Dim idx = 0
For Each s In entities
    idx = lines.IndexOf(s, idx)
    dictionary.Add(idx, s)
Next

For Each itm In dictionary
    lines.RemoveAt(itm.Key)
Next

For Each s In entities.ToList
    lines.Insert(1, s)
Next

Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("newfile.txt")
    For Each line As String In lines
        sw.WriteLine(line)
    Next
    sw.Flush()
    sw.Close()
End Using
```

Test Data

```
<!DOCTYPE DOC PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//DTD 38784STD-BV7//EN"[
<!ENTITY cdcs_5-35.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_5-35.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-2a.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-2A.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY GCS38849 SYSTEM "Graphics\GCS38849.cgm" NDATA cgm>
<!ENTITY GCS39016 SYSTEM "Graphics\GCS39016.cgm" NDATA cgm>
<doc service="xs" docid="BKw46" docstat="formal" verstatpg="ver" cycle="1" chglevel="1">
<front numcols="1">
<idinfo>
<?Pub Lcl _divid="100" _parentid="0">
<tmidno>Life with Pets</tmidno>
<chgnum>Change 1</chgnum>
<chgdate>2 August 2018</chgdate>
<chghistory>
<chginfo>
<!ENTITY CDCS_4-21B SYSTEM "Graphics\CDCS_4-21B.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY CDCS_4-24B SYSTEM "Graphics\CDCS_4-24B.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY CDCS_4-42B SYSTEM "Graphics\CDCS_4-42B.png" NDATA png>
<!ENTITY CDCS_MFW11 SYSTEM "Graphics\CDCS_MFW1.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY CDCS_blk10_Cont_consl_markingsworking1 SYSTEM "Graphics\CDCS_b
<chgtxt>Change 1</chgtxt>
<date>2 August 2018</date>
</front>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-19.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-19.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_3-5.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_3-5.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<body numcols="1">
<chapter>
<title>This is chapter 1</title>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-5.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-5.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-24.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-24.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<para0>
<title>Climb the ladder immedietly</title>
<para>Retrieve the cat.</para></para0></chapter>
<chapter>
<title>Don't forget to feed the dog</title>
<para0>
<!ENTITY GCS17777 SYSTEM "Graphics\GCS17777.cgm" NDATA cgm>
<!ENTITY GCS17782 SYSTEM "Graphics\GCS17782.cgm" NDATA cgm>
<!ENTITY GCS17783 SYSTEM "Graphics\GCS17783.cgm" NDATA cgm>
<!ENTITY GCS19983 SYSTEM "Graphics\GCS19983.cgm" NDATA cgm>
<!ENTITY GCS19984 SYSTEM "Graphics\GCS19984.cgm" NDATA cgm>
<!ENTITY cdcs_4-48.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_4-48.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<title>Prep for puppies</title>
<para>Puppies are cute</para></para0>
</chapter>
</body>
</doc>
```

The results is a file with all the <!Entity elements moved to the top of the document, but also remain in the body of the document.

The desired results is all <!.* elements to be moved to the top of the document and removed from the body of the document.

Thank you for all your help and patience with this question.
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved.

```
Dim largeFilePath As String = "largeFilePath"
Dim lines = File.ReadLines(largeFilePath).ToList 'don't use ReadAllLines
Dim reg = New Regex("\<\!NOTATION.*$|\<\!ENTITY.*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim entities = From line In lines
               Where reg.IsMatch(line)

Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
Dim idx = -1
For Each s In entities
    idx = lines.IndexOf(s, idx + 1)
    dictionary.Add(idx, s)
Next

Dim deletedItems = 0
For Each itm In dictionary
    lines.RemoveAt(itm.Key - deletedItems)
    deletedItems += 1
Next

For Each s In dictionary.Values
    lines.Insert(1, s)
Next

Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("newfile.txt")
    For Each line As String In lines
        sw.WriteLine(line)
    Next
    sw.Flush()
    sw.Close()
End Using
```